# Can I optimise repeating SVG elements in an html page?

Tags: html, svg, optimization

I'm using inline `<svg>` for my icons on an html page. I have a component which renders a table, often with hundreds of rows. In this case, every row of the table has the same inlined svg. Usually they are simple icons with just a few paths, but it got me wondering if there is some way to optimise this. In this scenario inlining is important, I don't want to have references to any external files. Is there some way for me to have the inlined svg just once, and refer to that same element somewhere else? Is this something I should even be worried about? Is the overhead of repeating inline svgs minimal?

Comment: please read about the [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#:~:text=The%20element%20takes%20nodes,and%20duplicates%20them%20somewhere%20else.&text=The%20effect%20is%20the%20same,cloned%20template%20elements%20in%20HTML5.)

Comment: @enxaneta "The <use> element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and duplicates them somewhere else." I don't want to reuse a node within the SVG document, I want to reuse the entire SVG document.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hundreds of table rows with one SVG, they all are (SVG) DOM elements you have to duplicate/repeat. There is no equivalent to SVGs `use` in HTML (*you could built that yourself with a Custom Element*)

If performance really really is an issue you need to test if creating SVGs Server Side (SSR) performs better (in your use case) than creating SVGs Client-Side... but you're probably talking micro-seconds..

Or if all your SVGs are 100% duplicates just a one liner with native JS [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) could be enough.

Or create a very simple **[W3C Standard Custom Element/Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)**
for clean semantic HTML:

```html
<h3>Who is afraid of Red, Yellow and Blue</h3>

<svg-icon bg="red"    ></svg-icon>
<svg-icon bg="yellow" ></svg-icon>
<svg-icon bg="blue"   ></svg-icon>

<style>
  svg-icon svg {
    --size: 120px;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
  }
  [bg=blue] svg{
    width:5px;
  }
  [bg=yellow] svg{
    width:15px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  customElements.define( "svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML =
          `<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>` +
            `<rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='${this.getAttribute("bg")}'/>` +
          `</svg>`;
      }});
</script>
```